# Create basic form in angular without using template and reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm trying to create a form in angular with only one input.

EX:

```js
  <form #creditForm="ngForm">
        <input
          id="storeCredit"
          name="storeCredit"
          type="checkbox"
          class="form-check-input"
        />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="storeCredit">
          You have
          {{ user.store_credit | float | currencyFormat : currency }} of store
          credit
        </label>
      </form>

FORM {{ creditForm | json }}
```

but I couldn't get any values on `FORM {{ creditForm | json }}`. Also since this is just a straightforward form is there a way that I could use inputs without the template or reactive forms? the value for the checkbox won't be sent to the backend anyway, it will just subtract the store credit from the total value.

Comment: Could you try {{ creditForm.value | json }} instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since this is just a straightforward form is there a way that I could use inputs without the template or reactive forms

This use case is exactly what template driven forms are for. [Here's an example using NgModel showing how simple this can be.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jaxec7?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
      <input
        id="storeCredit"
        name="storeCredit"
        type="checkbox"
        class="form-check-input"
        [(ngModel)]="myValue"
      />

      <div>
        My Value: {{myValue}}
      </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  myValue = false;
}
```

If you absolutely need/want to avoid the `FormsModule`, you're also able to do this by using the `value` attribute and `change` event. [Here's a similar stackblitz to the one above](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjhdhh?file=src%2Fmain.ts), except there's no `NgForms` import!

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
      <input
        id="storeCredit"
        name="storeCredit"
        type="checkbox"
        class="form-check-input"
        [value]="myValue"
        (change)="changed($event)"
      />      

      <div>
        My Value: {{myValue}}
      </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  myValue: boolean = false;

  changed(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.myValue = event.target.checked;
  }
}
```

Comment: ohhh. thank you. I thought that it's mandatory to use that angular forms like this `<form #form="ngForm"....` or reactive form. anyway thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crfeate a form not realted Angular you need use `ngNoform` (IT can be util when you want to send a post and open a new page). Then you can use a template reference variable to get the value

```
<form ngNoform #form 
       action="htpp://www.data.com" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input name="id">
</form>

@ViewChild('form') form!:HTMLFormElement

console.log(this.form.nativeElement)
console.log(this.form.nativeElement.elements[0])
console.log(this.form.nativeElement.elements[0].getAttribute('name'))
console.log(this.form.nativeElement.elements[0].value)
```